# Impact of correlation method using mice::quickpred()?

Tags: r, predictor, multiple-imputation, mice

I use Multiple Imputation with MICE in R for dealing with missings in my survey data. I have two huge question marks in my head at the moment:

1.) As I have quite a lot of predictors (actually all variables of my questionnaire) I followed the advice from *van Buuren* to use the function `quickpred()`. The only argument I put in by myself concerns: `minpuc = 0.5` (50% usable cases).

Now I am wondering whether I would also have to adjust the `method` argument. The function `quickpred()` uses Pearson by default. Other options are `“Spearman“`or `“Kendall“`. As far as I can see, there is no opportunity to combine these methods. Since I am using survey data (combination of dichotomous, ordinal and metric variables) I am not sure, if I had to use a different method than the default method. Are there any suggestions how to deal with that issue (i. e. combination of different scales of measurement) or am I good to go with `“Pearson“`?

2.) I have another question regarding the use of my predictors. In my data I have a variable that splits my data into two groups (Group 1/Group 2). Until now, I thought splitting the data set was not necessary - since I thought that the group variable (no missings at all btw) would be considered as a predictor. However, I figured out, that this group variable was only used as a predictors for only a few target variables. Probably the reason for that must be very low correlations with the target variables (as the 50% usable cases rule must have matched everywhere - due to no missings in that specific predictor). What would your advice be in that situation? Even if the group variable has not been considered as a direct predictor of most of my target variables, could it be possible that it still may have an indirect effect (e. g. My group variable is a direct predictor for target variable A. Variable A is in turn the predictor of target variable B - therefore my group variable has an indirect effect (via A) on the prediction of missings in B )?

Would you rather recommend splitting the data set before the MI process or should I use the argument include to make sure that the group variable is definitely use as a predictor (or could that even lead to a greater bias - using a predictor that might have only a very low correlation to target variables)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards
rNewbie